# What rights to assign during installation time to avoid 'Unable to write to' error message related to Windows VirutalStore?

Tags: windows, delphi-2009, rights, virtualstore

I have leagcy Windows program (written in Delphi 2009, that uses Rx TFormStorage component), that tries to write ini file into Windows directory. Of course, Windows 10 does not allow it, instead, Windows 10 writes and reads this ini file from the C:\Users\\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows directory. It works normally, however, sometimes the users receive error message '`Unable to write to`'.

Why is that? For all that Windows is not required to give access to C:/Windows, it should redirect the user to the VirtualStore but why this redirection gives such error meesage? As I understand, then users are not required to have special rights to write and read in VirtualStore directory even it is VirtualStore/Windows directory?

So, why there is this error message and what user rights can I grant to the end user in my InnoSetup installation script (which is run with Administrator privileges) with the aim to get rid of the error message '`Unable to write to`'?

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/files-going-to-cwindows-instead-of-virtualstore/f230007b-892d-47b4-a569-627929231f8b

Comment: It is the behavior of a program without a manifest that declares itself compatible with UAC.  Explicitly disabling the remapping to VirtualStore with an admin policy [is possible](https://interworks.com/blog/dsmith/2011/09/21/disabling-windows-7-virtual-store/), it would have to be re-enabled to keep your app functioning.

Comment: You ar trying to say: if the program is compatible with UAC, then it is trying to write in the VirtualStore and the Windows allows it. If the program is not compatible with UAC, it is trying to write in the VirtualStore (via redirection), but Windows does not allow it in this case?

Comment: No, only the 2nd sentence is correct.  If your program would have the manifest then it will try to write to c:\windows, that's not going to work.